# K-theoretic derivation of Bézout theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, intersection-theory

In the paper "$K$-Theory and Intersection Theory" by Henri Gillet in *Handbook of K-theory*, 2005 ([link behind paywall at Springerlink](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-540-27855-9_7)), the author says:

"When the ground field $k = \mathbb C$, Bézout’s theorem can be proved using integral cohomology. However, prior to the development of étale cohomology for curves over fields of characteristic $p$, one had to use algebraic methods to prove Bézout’s theorem, and there is still no cohomology theory which makes proving similar theorems over an arbitrary base, including $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, possible."

I understand we may not have a good theory of Chow groups over $\mathrm{Spec}(Z)$. However from the title of the paper a natural question arises to me. Why can't we use K-theory to prove Bézout's theorem over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$? From the references I checked, it seems we do have the projective bundle formula in this setting. So I think we can derive the Bézout formula from the formula $[O_Y] \cup [O_Z] = [O_{Y\cap Z}]$ in $K_0(P^n)$ (in case of transverse intersection), am I wrong? As far as I could see, the question is not answered in the rest of the paper.

Comment: I don't think the issue is that we don't know the existence of the product, K_0 with supports works for regular noetherian schemes and products play well with supports. I would suspect the issue is making sense of the degree of a subvariety in this context and relating it to K-theory with supports